# Não inserir dados iguais no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Estou pegando dados de um XML, convertendo para `array` e inserindo no banco de dados. Mas preciso somente resultados que não existem ainda.

Segue abaixo meu código, já tentei de várias outras formas, nenhuma com um bom resultado. No código abaixo sempre cai no `já tem no banco` mesmo não existindo nenhum resultado igual.

```
foreach ($dados as $grupo) {//mostra os grupos existentes
    foreach ($grupo as $subgrupo) {//mostra cada subgrupo
        $ci->db->trans_start();
        if (!$ci->db->select('nome')->from('tipo_produto')->where('nome', $subgrupo->attributes()->SubGrupo)) {
            $arraysubgrupos = array(
                'nome' => "" . $subgrupo->attributes()->SubGrupo . "",
            );
            $ci->Cadastros_model->incluir('tipo_produto', $arraysubgrupos);
            $id_produto = mysql_insert_id();
            echo "ok";
        } else {
            echo "ja tem no banco";
        }
        $ci->db->trans_complete();
        $arraygrupos = array(
            'nome' => "" . $grupo->attributes()->Grupo . "",
            'tipo_id_tipo_produto' => "" . $id_produto . ""
        );
        //$ci->Cadastros_model->incluir('categoria', $arraygrupos);
        $id_grupo = mysql_insert_id();

        foreach ($subgrupo as $produto) {//exibi os produtos
            if ($produto->attributes()->codigo != "") {
                $arrayprodutos = array(
                    'id_produto' => "" . $produto->attributes()->codigo . "",
                    'nome' => "" . $produto->attributes()->nome . "",
                    'descricao' => "" . $produto->attributes()->descricao . "",
                    'valor' => "" . $produto->attributes()->preco . "",
                    'tipo_produto_id_tipo' => "" . $id_produto . "",
                    'categoria_id_categoria' => "" . $id_grupo . ""
                );
                //$ci->Cadastros_model->incluir('produtos', $arrayprodutos);  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: O XML possui linhas com dados exatamente iguais? Ou por exemplo linhas com o id_produto igual e as outras informações diferentes?

Comment: Definir uma chave primária (ou apenas um índice único) na tabela de seu banco de dados não resolveria facilmente seu problema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Corrija:

```
$ci->db->select('nome')->from('tipo_produto')->where('nome', $subgrupo->attributes()->SubGrupo)
```

Alterando para:

```
$ci->db->select('nome')->from('tipo_produto')->where('nome', $subgrupo->attributes()->SubGrupo)->get()->row()
```

Da forma como você fez sempre irá retornar VERDADEIRO, você precisa concluir a consulta e verificar se existe alguma linha (como sugeri acima).

Tambem recomendo trocar

```
mysql_insert_id()
```

por:

```
$ci->db->insert_id()
```

Assim você mantém a estrutura padronizada.

Comment: Muito obrigado Vieira funcionou perfeitamente agora !